# ES6 on Atom with linter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, atom-editor, eslint

Any clue why I'm getting this parsing error on Atom?
[image]

My .eslintrc:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  }
}
```

My package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.0"
  },
```

My Atom packages:
[image]

Comment: Probably because class properties is an experimental feature in Stage 2, with Babel. Have you tried adding the [`babel-eslint`](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) parser?